# How to parse Json file only as a raw string value in cpp. I am using nlohmann json library for parsing

Tags: c++, json, parsing, nlohmann-json

I have a json file

which looks something like this

```
{accessvalue: xyz-verylongvalue ,Type:abc}
```

I am parsing it using nlohmann json as given below:

```
std::ifstream ifs(PATH);
auto config= json::parse(ifs);
if (config.find("accessvalue")!=config.end()){  
string somevalue= config["accessvalue"].get<string>();
}
```

The above gives me a string value but next function expects the value in raw form.
how do i convert "somevalue" to raw string or parse only the raw part.

Answer (score 0):

std::string has a `c_str()` member, which returns C string (raw string). So, you need `somevalue.c_str()`.

Comment: It does not help. I need to it to behave exactly R"(stringvalue)" works because this seems to work for my code and runs with run time errors

Comment: Can you show the exact signature of your "next function"?